# calculate column percentage difference

Tags: r

My df have more than 2 columns (for example, 4). I want to calculate the percentage difference of the column 2-4 compared to column 1.

```
time1          time2            time3          time4
  1              5                1             10
  2              2                2              4
  3              6                3             12
```

My code is:

```
timepoint <- colnames(df)[2:4]
for (x in timepoint){
df$x <- 100*(df$x/df$time1-1)
}
```

What's wrong with this for function? Thank you!

Comment: your not far away, but you cant do `df$x`, you need to do `df[[x]]`, as otherwise it looks for a variable called `x`. So use `df[[x]] <- 100*(df[[x]]/df$time1-1)`. But loops are nt needed you could do `100*(df[-1] / df[ ,1] - 1)`

Comment: @Sotos Thank you!! works!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a too long answer, but I think it's a start step

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)

df <- tribble(
  ~time1, ~time2, ~time3, ~time4,
  1, 5, 1, 10,
  2, 2, 2, 4,
  3, 6, 3, 12
)

df_tidy <- df %>% 
  mutate(id = 1:nrow(.)) %>% 
  gather(time, value, time1:time4) %>% 
  mutate(id_base = ifelse(time == "time1", TRUE, FALSE))

df_calc <- filter(df_tidy, id_base == FALSE)

df_base <- df_tidy %>% 
  filter(id_base== TRUE) %>% 
  select(id, value_base = value)

df_join <- df_calc %>% 
  left_join(
    df_base, 
    by = "id"
  )

df_join %>% 
  mutate(diff = (value / value_base) * 100)
# A tibble: 9 × 4
     id  time value  diff
  <int> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 time2     5   500
2     2 time2     2   100
3     3 time2     6   200
4     1 time3     1   100
5     2 time3     2   100
6     3 time3     3   100
7     1 time4    10  1000
8     2 time4     4   200
9     3 time4    12   400
```